# Deferred Promises in Function does not Defer Execution of Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I'm struggling with deferred promises.  I have a very ugly string:

me, company name, SSQ ID, the company you are working for (Extraction/XTR/8North) and the tier assigned to your company in question #17.
    |Y132~ 
    |Y133~ 
    |Y134~ 
    
    |Y138~ 
    |Y139~
    |Y140~
    
    |Y141~
    |Y142~
    |Y143~

that I have to replace each occurrence of a "|Y000~" with a URL link.  That part of the code is working correctly. The problem is that I can't figure out how to use a promise to wait on the function (which includes deferral of multiple promises) to wait until the function finishes before moving on.

I have this in my "convertString" function:

```
getAllClusterLinks(indices, returnString)
returnString = $scope.returnString;
```

Here is the convetString function:

```
function convertClusterText(questions, field) {
    angular.forEach(questions, function (value, key) {
        if (value.vchTextBeforeQuestionCluster != null) {
            var str = value.vchTextBeforeQuestionCluster;
            var returnString = str.replaceAll('|B', '<b>');
            returnString = returnString.replaceAll("|b", "</b>");
            returnString = returnString.replaceAll("|+", "<br/>");
            returnString = returnString.replaceAll("|L", "<");
            returnString = returnString.replaceAll("|R", ">");
            returnString = returnString.replaceAll("|T", "<table border='1'>");
            returnString = returnString.replaceAll("|/T", "</table>");
            returnString = returnString.replaceAll("|S", "<tr>");
            returnString = returnString.replaceAll("|/S", "</tr>");
            returnString = returnString.replaceAll("|C", "<td>");
            returnString = returnString.replaceAll("|/C", "</td>");
            returnString = returnString.replaceAll("|A", "&#39;");
            returnString = returnString.replaceAll("|Q", "&amp;");
            returnString = returnString.replaceAll("|P", "&#59;");
            returnString = returnString.replaceAll("|W", "&#34;");
            returnString = returnString.replaceAll("|H", "<hr style='width: 100%;'>");
            returnString = returnString.replaceAll("|U", "<span style='text-decoration:underline'>");
            returnString = returnString.replaceAll("|x", "</span>");
            returnString = returnString.replaceAll("|N", "<span style='color:black'>");
            returnString = returnString.replaceAll("|D", "<span style='color:blue'>");
            returnString = returnString.replaceAll("|E", "<span style='color:red'>");
            returnString = returnString.replaceAll("|G", "<span style='color:gray'>");
            if (returnString.indexOf("|Y") >= 0) {
                var indices = [];
                var linkCode;

                indices = getIndicesOf("|Y", returnString, true);

                if (indices.length > 1) {

                    getAllClusterLinks(indices, returnString)
                    .then(function () {
                        returnString = $scope.returnString;

                    })
                           value.vchTextBeforeQuestionCluster = returnString;



                }
                else {
                    linkCode = getLink(returnString);
                    contractorService.gethyperlink(linkCode)
                    .success(function (data) {
                        var vchUrl = data[0].vchUrl;
                        var docID = getDocumentID(vchUrl);
                        var vchLinkName = data[0].vchLinkName;
                        questions[key].document = docID;
                        var yay = '<a href="" ng-click="getDocument(cluster)">' + vchLinkName + '</a>';
                        var yCode = "|Y" + linkCode + "~";
                        returnString = returnString.replaceAll(yCode, yay);
                        value.vchTextBeforeQuestionCluster = returnString;
                    })
                }

            }
            else {
                value.vchTextBeforeQuestionCluster = returnString;

            }


        }
    });
};
```

I need "getAllClusterLinks" to complete before executing the next line. Here is the code for "getAllClusterLinks":

```
function getAllClusterLinks(indices, returnString) {
    var promises = [];
    var times = 0
    var endIndex = 0;
    angular.forEach(indices, function (value, key) {
        endIndex = getEndIndicesOf("~", returnString, value);
        linkCode = getMultiLinks(returnString, value, endIndex)
        var promise = getClusterLinks(linkCode, returnString);
        promises.push(promise);
    })

    return $q.all(promises);
}
function getClusterLinks(linkCode, returnString) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $scope.returnString = returnString;
    contractorService.gethyperlink(linkCode)
    .success(function (data) {
        var vchUrl = data[0].vchUrl;
        var end = vchUrl.length;
        var docID = vchUrl.substring(vchUrl.indexOf("=") + 1, end);
        var vchLinkName = data[0].vchLinkName;
        var yay = '<a href="" ng-click="getDocument(' + docID + ')">' + vchLinkName + '</a>';
        var yCode = "|Y" + linkCode + "~";
        $scope.returnString = $scope.returnString.replaceAll(yCode, yay);
    })
    return deferred.promise;

}
```

The above code works as expected, but I need it to finish first before setting the line `returnString = $scope.returnString;`.

Tried this but it doesn't work:

```
                     getAllClusterLinks(indices, returnString)
                    .then(function () {
                        returnString = $scope.returnString;

                    })
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you are setting `$scope.returnString = returnString;` inside the function too. Explain in more detail how this should be working. I think you want the string returned each time but it's not clear exactly what objective is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$q.all(promises) returns a promise. You should be able to use then() .

```
 getAllClusterLinks(indices, returnString).then(function() {
     returnString = $scope.returnString;
});
```

[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q][1]

**EDIT: you should resolve your deferred object**

sidenote: I believe success() is already deprecated, you should use .then too

```
function getClusterLinks(linkCode, returnString) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $scope.returnString = returnString;
    contractorService.gethyperlink(linkCode)
    .success(function (data) {
        var vchUrl = data[0].vchUrl;
        var end = vchUrl.length;
        var docID = vchUrl.substring(vchUrl.indexOf("=") + 1, end);
        var vchLinkName = data[0].vchLinkName;
        var yay = '<a href="" ng-click="getDocument(' + docID + ')">' + vchLinkName + '</a>';
        var yCode = "|Y" + linkCode + "~";
        $scope.returnString = $scope.returnString.replaceAll(yCode, yay);
        deferred.resolve(); // resolve here
    })
    return deferred.promise;

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that and the "then" never gets hit.

Comment: you are not resolving your deferred object. See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks!  adding deferred.resolve();  did it!  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the subsequent line in a *then()* callback:

```
getAllClusterLinks(indices, returnString)
    .then(function() {
        returnString = $scope.returnString;
    });
```

For more info about promises within angular, see [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)